# How to do wpf datavalidation with Ado.net

Tags: wpf, validation, ado.net, dataset, datatable

How can i use data validation mechanisms with ado.net datatable or datasets.
I have an input form which i am binding to a datatable.Now i want to do input validation how can i do that.I have tried using validationRules but i cant bind parameters to it.I tried using idataerrorinfo but cant get a clue.can someone provide some input..?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that can be helpful:

[Displaying Data Validation Messages in WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2008/06/27/displaying-data-validation-messages-in-wpf.aspx) - By Beth Massi

She mentions in there the following:

> *"If you are using DataSets on your WPF
>   or Windows Forms, the DataRowView
>   already implements this interface so
>   you can just add validation to your
>   DataTable partial classes and you're
>   good to go"*

Comment: In that she is talking about typed datasets.But in my case it is a normal dataset